# Importing TypeScript modules with dependency injection in NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

In my NestJS application - I have TypeScript classes that have other classes and values injected into them. The only thing is that I'm importing the TypeScript classes with `import` statements, and also using the DI system to inject them. Is there some way to remove the import statements and just let the DI system handle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

- `import` -> class reference
- DI -> class instantiation
- Matching by string token is possible, but class reference is preferred.

---

### Encapsulation

The dependency injection system mainly handles the instantiation of the classes. This is great, because you do not need to care about the transitive dependencies that the class you want to inject requires.

Example: I want to use the `UserService` in my `UserController`. The `UserService` requires the `UserModel` for instantiation. However, this second-level dependency is hidden in the `UserController`. This is great because when the `UserService` gets a new dependency like a `LoggingService`, the `UserController` does not have to be changed.

So instead of

```
class UserController {
  constructor() {
    const userModel = new UserModel();
    this.userService = new UserService(userModel);
  }
}
```

you can just do

```
class UserController {
  // the transitive dependency on UserModel is hidden
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}
}
```

### Class Reference

But for the DI to know which service to inject you need some link from the `@Inject` declaration to an actual class to instantiate. Of course, this mechanism depends on the implementation of the DI system. The reference could be by name (string matching), by interface (DI decides which implementation to use: `UserService`  -> `UserServiceImpl` / `MockUserServiceImpl`) or in the default case of nestjs directly by the class to be instantiated.

Although matching by name is possible in nestjs, matching by class is preferred because it makes refactoring much easier.

When you create a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers) you can choose what kind of token you want to use for the matching. This is needed, when you want to inject a value (no class for matching)

```
const connectionProvider = {
  provide: 'Connection',
  useValue: connection,
};

@Module({
  providers: [connectionProvider],
})
```

or a dynamically instantiated class.

```
const configServiceProvider = {
  provide: ConfigService,
  useClass: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? DevelopmentConfigService
    : ProductionConfigService,
};

@Module({
  providers: [configServiceProvider],
})
```