# Inject nestjs service from another module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I've got a `PlayersModule` and an `ItemsModule`.

I want to use the `ItemsService` in the `PlayersService`.

When I add it by injection:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from 'nestjs-typegoose';
import { ModelType, Ref } from 'typegoose';
import { Player } from './player.model';
import { Item } from '../items/item.model';
import { ItemsService } from '../items/items.service';

@Injectable()
export class PlayersService {
    constructor(
        @InjectModel(Player) private readonly playerModel: ModelType<Player>,
        private readonly itemsService: ItemsService){}
```

I get this nest error :

> [Nest] 11592   - 2018-8-13 11:42:17   [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't
>   resolve dependencies of the PlayersService (+, ?). Please make sure
>   that the argument at index [1] is available in the current context.

Both modules are imported in the `app.module.ts`. Both services are working alone in their module.

Answer (score 376, accepted):

You have to **export** the `ItemsService` in the module that provides it:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [ItemsController],
  providers: [ItemsService],
  exports: [ItemsService]
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
})
export class ItemsModule {}
```

and then import the exporting **module** in the module that uses the service:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [PlayersController],
  providers: [PlayersService],
  imports: [ItemsModule]
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
})
export class PlayersModule {}
```

⚠️ Don't add the same provider to multiple modules. Export the provider, import the module. ⚠️

Comment: Ok, thanks you. So i have to import ItemsModule into PlayersModule even if it is already known by AppModule ?

Comment: If you want to use it in the PlayersModule, yes.

Comment: I used @KimKern 's suggestion, still see the errors that the injected service is not recognized.

Comment: @Liangjun There are also other reasons why a dependency can not be injected. You can always open a new question.

Comment: I actually had the problem solved by just restarting my Visual Studio Code. strange. Thanks.

Comment: Was trying to import the Service itself, turned out importing the module itself worked. Thank you

Comment: @nasta did you still need to additionally import the service inside PlayersService?
i.e. `import { ItemsService } from '../items/items.service';`. 
In addition, is there some kind of decorator we use here inside the constructor?
`@Inject private readonly itemsService: ItemsService`

Comment: @baku Yes, you need the js import. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51516526/4694994

Comment: Currently this won't work... You will still need to add ItemsService in the providers of the providers array of the PlayersModule

Comment: @OmarHossamAhmed You should not add the `ItemsService` to the `PlayersModule`. Did you export the `ItemsService` in the `ItemsModule` before importing it in the `PlayersModule`?

Comment: Yes I was working on something similar and it only seemed to work when I added it in the providers module. It was a service registered in module x  and exported by said module. Now, the weirdest thing I tried it again now and it worked! Sorry for my false information, but I noticed some weird behaviour with dependency injection lately.,

Comment: Hi Kim Kern. This works perfect sir. I had one problem. I want to share the TypeOrm repository from one module to other. I tried this in case of Repository but it didn't work.

Comment: @SushantKeni Thanks, I'm glad this answer is helpful. :-) It's difficult to answer your question without seeing your code. Consider opening a new question for it and include the relevant code snippets.

Comment: Is it possible to have a service class without @Injectable annotattion, and also this class does not belong to any module?, I saw an example like that, where this service belongs to a commons folder, and it was registered in another module in the the providers array, and it injected in other service's constructor method

Comment: @Hector I am not sure I understood your use case fully, but I had these two thoughts: You can define regular JS classes outside of nests application container and then just create them where you need them (-> no injection possible). Also, there are global modules, that only need to be imported once (also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55181002/4694994). If this does not help, consider opening a new question and add more details to it, ideally a minimal code snippet explaining your scenario.

Comment: If you get into circular. Use `forwardRef`, https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency

Comment: My mistake was not adding `@` before `Module` decorator  and `nest.js` didn't complain about this

Comment: after trying this solution out I keep getting an error `Error: Cannot find module 'src/item/item.service'`

the app I'm working on has an `app.module.ts` which imports both modules. could that be the issue?

Comment: Thanks, alghough this is terrible...It would have been nicer to have a "ModuleWithProviders" to use in the root and then share providers.
It doesn't make much sense to me exporting a service...in Angular export is mostly for Components and Modules...Providers are handled differently! Or at least, I never exported a provider in Angular...
Thanks a lot by the way, it worked!

Answer (score 42):

Let' say you want to use AuthService from AuthModule in my TaskModule's controller

for that, you need to export authService from AuthModule

```
@Module({
    imports: [
     ....
    ],
    providers: [AuthService],
    controllers: [AuthController],
    exports:[AuthService]
  })
export class AuthModule {}
```

then in TaskModule, you need to import AuthModule (note: import AuthModule not the AuthService in TaskModule)

```
@Module({
    imports:[
      AuthModule
    ],
    controllers: [TasksController],
    providers: [TasksService]
  })
export class TasksModule {}
```

Now you should be able to use DI in TaskController

```
@Controller('tasks')
export class TasksController {
   constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 17):

The question is answered by Kim Kern. But I just want to remind people who read through this comment. Whenever you get this error, you should follow these steps that may help you easily figure out where the stuck is:

- Make sure the Module which provides providers was imported.
- Make sure the provider which you are using is exported.

For example, you have category module which contains category service, post module has post service and it has category service as a dependency:

```
@Module({
    controllers: [CategoryController],
    providers: [CategoryService],
    exports: [CategoryService] // Remember to export
  })
export class CategoryModule {}
```

And

```
@Module({
    imports: [CategoryModule], // Make sure you imported the module you are using
    controllers: [PostController],
    providers: [PostService]
  })
export class PostModule {}
```

Don't forget to use this annotation.
Nest uses this to detect singleton class.
In spring boot - Java, this one used to be called Bean. Read more:

```
@Injectable()  
export class PostService {
  constructor(private readonly categoryService: CategoryService // This will be auto injected by Nestjs Injector) {}
}
```

Comment: Hello @Justin I did the same but it throws error that service function not found, is not a function

Comment: Can I have your giot repo or sandbox code then I can take a look at? @RiteshKhatri

Comment: Sorry I cannot share the code.

Comment: @RiteshKhatri Maybe you missing add `@Injectable` in PlayersService class, so NestJS doesn't understand the function import from other module

Answer (score 5):

I solved my problem by removing `@Inject()` from the argument in my constructor that was passing the exported service.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you faced the same problem i had. My scenario was 2 sibling custom modules (user, auth) that needed to use each other's services. I used *circular DI* to solve it. please check this [link](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency)

Let me know whether if it solved your issue, maybe I can advise you further.

Comment: I thought this problem just because services didn't export, it's different from Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer by Kim Kern nowadays we should add only injected service into our service without any decorators (@Inject() doesn't required). After that it will work right. That was my mistake and probably can help others.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by changing the way of importing the constant string (TOKEN) used in @Inject()) of my provider... be careful using index.ts whith export * from module.ts, nest won't resolve the dependecy

Answer (score -1):

Steps 1. Export the file that you want
Step 2. Import the whole module.

I initially made a mistake of adding the file as provider and also adding the module which was throwing error.

Answer (score -1):

None of the responses worked for me. Until I changed the constructor of my using/importing service from:

```
constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {}
```

to:

```
constructor(@Inject(UsersService) private usersService: UsersService) {}
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Of course you have to import Inject, and UsersService