# Calling serviceA from serviceB while maintaining serviceB module context

Tags: javascript, web-frameworks, nestjs

With nestjs framework in mind, I have a couple of services exposed as API. Each service has its own module and specific httpmodule config.

ServiceA needs to make a call to ServiceB. In this case I have two options:
1 - Perform an http request.
2 - Consume serviceB within service A.

For option 1 there is a problem. ServiceA has its own HTTPModule config and therefore to perform an http request I need to override HttpModule configurations. Also, it puts an unnecessary load on my service sending http requests.

Option 2 seems to have an issue where ServiceA HttpModule configurations are being used for ServiceB.

Question:
IS there a way to consume ServiceB in ServiceA but maintain the module context integrity of ServiceB?

For clarity here is the structure:

```
-src
  --serviceA
    -- serviceA.module.ts
    -- serviceA.service.ts
  --serviceB
    -- serviceB.module.ts
    -- serviceB.service.ts
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inject nestjs service from another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819504/inject-nestjs-service-from-another-module)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

In serviceA.module:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        ServiceBModule
    ],
})
export class ServiceA {}
```

in ServiceB module I had to add the exports like so:

```
@Module({
    exports: [ServiceBService]
})
export class ServiceBModule {}
```

in serviceA.service

```
import { ServiceBService } from 'src/serviceB/serviceB.service';

constructor(private readonly serviceB: ServiceBService) { }
```

Use serviceB as you normally would in your code.