# NestJS Global Modules in tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

Is there a way to automatically provide all `@Global`modules into a `TestModule` ? (i.e without having to import them, the same way the main application works)

So far, I had to make sure to insert any global modules into the `import` list of my call:

```
await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        GlobalModule1,
        GlobalModule2
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Global modules always have to be imported once for their providers to be available globally. This holds true for tests *and* the main application, see the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules).

> Global modules shall be registered only once, in best case by the
>   root or core module. Afterwards, the `CatsService` provider will be
>   ubiquitous, although `CatsModule` won't be imported.

So there's no way around importing them. You can make it easier by creating a `CommonsModule` that imports all your global modules. You can then import the `CommonsModule` instead of each module in your `AppModule` and your tests.

Note though, that having lots of global dependencies is a code smell. Also, in unit tests you typically want to test a class in isolation from any other dependencies. If you import the global modules, you will test against the actual providers.

> Making everything global is not a good decision. The global modules
>   are available to reduce the amount of necessary boilerplate. The
>   imports array is still the best way to make the module API
>   transparent.